# Why does this Ti.UI.WebView.fireEvent() call throw an exception when a listener is present?

Tags: events, webview, titanium

I create a new window with

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({url:'page.js'});
win.listeners = {
   'type': function(e){ alert('test'); }
}
win.open();
```

Inside page.js, I add the specified listeners to a Ti.UI.WebView inside the window.

```
for (var type in win.listeners) {
    Ti.API.info(win.listeners[type])
    webView.addEventListener(type, win.listeners[type]);
}
```

Ti.API.info(win.listeners['type']) prints the function as "<KrollCallback: 0xb272160>"

A call to webView.fireEvent('type') executes fine if there are no listeners. But if I add listeners to the webView as above, the call to fireEvent throws an exception.

What is KrollCallback and why does fireEvent crash if there are listeners present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that using url:'page.js' with createWindow() starts a new context. This type of setup will work if page.js is like this:

```
exports.getWindow(config) {

   var webView = Ti.UI.createWebView({});

   for (var type in config.listeners) {
      webView.addEventListener(type, config.listeners[type]);
   }
}
```

Then, use the window like this:

```
var win = require('page').getWindow({
   listeners = {
      'event_type': function(e){ alert('event_type test'); }
   }
});

win.open();
```